# Intermittent java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError occuring for JNI calls to native rust methods on Android 9 devices

Tags: java, android, rust, java-native-interface

I am seeing intermittent crashes due to java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError for JNI calls to native rust methods on Android 9 devices. The issue is intermittent and does not occur every time on the device. It is working for older versions of android.

I am loading the native library inside the static block in the Application's driver class. Also application's OnCreate makes sure that libraries are loaded successfully otherwise it throws an exception.

The native APIs are part of rust package which I own and it exposes the native APIs via JNI layer.
I am running a Android JobScheduler JobService periodically which calls one of the native methods and in that intermittently we are seeing UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Please note that JobService is part of MyApplication and it runs in the same process.

The issue is seen intermittently only on newer Android N devices and for rest of the older versions it is working fine.

Does anybody have any idea on cause of the issue and how can it be fixed?

```
Android Build details: 
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.build.version.release=9
ro.build.version.sdk=28 
ro.build.type=user
```

```
public class NativeLibraryLoader {
    private static final Throwable INIT_ERROR;
    static {
        Throwable error = null;
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("my_library");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            error = t;
        }
        INIT_ERROR = error;
    }

    /**
     * Check native library availability.
     */
    public static void checkAvailability() {
        if (INIT_ERROR != null) {
            if (INIT_ERROR instanceof RuntimeException) {
                throw (RuntimeException) INIT_ERROR;
            } else if (INIT_ERROR instanceof Error) {
                throw (Error) INIT_ERROR;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(INIT_ERROR);
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 *  Class for Android application.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getName();

    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "MyApplication onCreate started");
        super.onCreate();

        // Load native library
        NativeLibraryLoader.checkAvailability();

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        initializeApplication();
        Log.i(TAG, "MyApplication onCreate Completed");
    }

    /**
     * Initializes all the components of the application.
     */
    private void initializeApplication() {
        //perform initialization of application
        //schedule MyJobService job to run every 20 mins and call myNativeMethod
    }
}

public class MyJobService extends JobService {
    private static final String TAG = MyJobService.class.getName();

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartJob called for MyJobService.");
        MyNativeClient.myNativeMethod(getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().dataDir, getAndroidEncKey(getApplicationContext()), new MyEventCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void myCallbackEvent(String payload) {
                                // perform some operations
                            }
                        });
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartJob for MyJobService finished");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before completion");
        return true;
    }
}
```

It throws java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError,No implementation found for void MyNativeClient.myNativeMethod

Comment: Working on older version of what? Native library or Android?

Comment: Older android versions.